# Can't schedule an UILocalNotification x days from now

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I've been trying now for way too many hours without finding the problem/solution. this code is supposed to schedule a notification x days from now by comparing wd(the selected weekday) and item.itemDayName(Int of the current weekday). Right now the code only works when wd == 7, as wd == 7 --> all weekdays are selected (wd 0-6 = sun-sat). I will appreciate any feedback given, thank you.

```
- (void)scheduleNotificationWithItem:(ToDoItem *)item andWeekday:(int)wd{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    if (wd < 7) {
        [dateComps setYear:item.itemYear];
        [dateComps setMonth:item.itemMonth];
        if (item.itemDayName != (wd + 1)) {
            int result = (wd + 1) - item.itemDayName;
            result = result + item.itemDay;
            [dateComps setDay:result];
        }
        else{
            [dateComps setDay:item.itemDay];
        }
    }
    else {
        [dateComps setYear:item.itemYear];
        [dateComps setMonth:item.itemMonth];
        [dateComps setDay:item.itemDay];
    }
    [dateComps setHour:item.itemHour];
    [dateComps setMinute:item.itemMinute];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    //localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(1*60)];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    if (wd < 7) {
        [localNotif setRepeatInterval: NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth];
    }
    else {
        [localNotif setRepeatInterval: NSCalendarUnitDay]; //Repeat daily
    }

    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Time to take %@!", nil),
                            item.itemName];
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
    localNotif.alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Piller", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:item.itemName forKey:item.itemKeyName];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Comment: Issue seems to lay in "[localNotif setRepeatInterval: NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth];"

Comment: changed it to NSWeekCalendarUnit